# Regular Expression working only for alternative click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex

I am using ngpattern for validation but my error message is showing for alternative change. Error message should show if it is empty or only special characters are available.

```
<textarea name="title" ng-model="title" required ng-pattern="/^[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g" ></textarea>
<input name="test" ng-model="test" required />
<p ng-hide="form.title.$error.pattern || form.title.$error.required">
      Error 1: {{form.$error}}<br />
</p>
</form>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wkzab/1033/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use ng-show to show error when at least one of errors is present.

```
<form name="form" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<textarea name="title" ng-model="widget.title" required ng-pattern="/^[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g" ></textarea>
    <span>{{form.title.$error | json }}</span>
    <p ng-show="form.title.$error.required || form.title.$error.pattern">
    Error 1: {{form.$error}}<br />
    </p>
</form>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/d2w6wzex/2/